# Changes not visible in the UI after updating data in the DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

When I modify values via `DataContext` to set data for `CheckBox`, why does it return original value whem scrolling down or scrolling up? Is there any way to recover?

When I scroll down or up I expect it to not return the checkboxes to their original values.

---

**XAML Code**

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="list_account_instagram"
          Background="#DDDDDD"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Width="0.4*"
                                           Binding="{Binding STT}"
                                           Header="#" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="0.35*" Binding="{Binding CHECK, Mode=OneTime}">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                <Border Background="Transparent">
                    <CheckBox Name="checkallins" Click="Checkallins_Click"/>
                </Border>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

        <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UID}" Width="*"
                                           Header="UID" />
        <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PASSWORD}" Width="*"
                                           Header="Password"/>
        <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding COOKIE}" Width="*"
                                           Header="Cookie"/>
        <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TEN}" Width="*"
                                           Header="Tên"/>
        <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AVATAR}" Width="*"
                                           Header="Avatar"/>
        <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TT}" Width="*"
                                           Header="Tình Trạng"/>
        <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MESSAGE}" Width="*"
                                           Header="Trạng Thái"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**C#**

```cs
private void Checkallins_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkallins.IsChecked.Value)
    {
        if (list_account_instagram.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list_account_instagram.Items.Count; i++)
            {
              GetCell(list_account_instagram, i, 1).DataContext = new { CHECK = true };
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (list_account_instagram.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list_account_instagram.Items.Count; i++)
            {
              GetCell(list_account_instagram, i, 1).DataContext = null;
              GetCell(list_account_instagram, i, 1).DataContext = new { CHECK = false };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To better describe the problematic behavior, there is video: https://files.fm/u/2xxgqrqra#/view/p4jw246e3

Comment: Are you handling your scroll up/scroll down anyhow? Do you make some changes on the data?

Comment: @Tatranskymedved i have no function to handle scroll up and scroll down

Answer (score 0):

Issue is related to using **`OneTime` binding**. This will cause that data are only loaded during initialization, but after any change (either in UI or from the code), it won't affect the collection itself.

This is causing the problem when you see different things in the "UI" and different things in the "code-behind". If you would debug actual values (when pressing header of `DataGrid`), you would be surprised where those values would come from.

Fix is pretty simple, you must update the `Binding` mode. Instead of this:

```xml
Binding="{Binding CHECK, Mode=OneTime}">
```

You should use:

```xml
Binding="{Binding CHECK}">
<!-- or this -->
Binding="{Binding CHECK, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

---

EDIT: from comments of OP it looks that the problem is also setting the `bool` value for the items in the `DataGrid`. You should not be assigning new objects there, instead you should be working with the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid`. You can achieve this by:

```
var isChecked = checkallins.IsChecked.Value;

foreach(var item in list_account_instagram.Items)
{
    // Put instead of `MyClass` actual class you are using (prob. `InstagramAccount`)
    var myItem = item as MyClass;

    if(item != null)
    {
        myItem.CHECK = isChecked;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I call `GetCell(list_account_instagram, i, 1).DataContext = new { CHECK = true };` I get an error like below, is there any way to fix it?  `System.InvalidOperationException: 'A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'CHECK' of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.Boolean]'.'`